# create new workspace in ros groovy

Tags: bash, workspace, ros

I am new at ubuntu and Ros. I try to create a workspace by looking this tutorial..
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment#Create_a_ROS_Workspace

I did like that;

> source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
>
> rosws init ~/groovy_workspace /opt/ros/groovy

than it says "Type 'source /home/aysebetul/groovy_workspace/setup.bash' to change into this environment. Add that source command to the bottom of your ~/.bashrc to set it up every time you log in."

What is this warning?

anyway I continue to tutorial,

> mkdir ~/groovy_workspace/sandbox
>
> rosws set ~/groovy_workspace/sandbox
>
> source ~/groovy_workspace/setup.bash
>
> echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

in tutorial the output : /home/your_user_name/groovy_workspace/sandbox:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks

but in my case -> /opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks

I don't know is this problem. I do same things why the outputs are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should literally follow the given advice:

- enter 'source /home/aysebetul/groovy_workspace/setup.bash' (without
  quotes) in bash shell or
- add the same command to .bashrc file in your
  home folder.

The file "setup.bash" is apparently responsible for setting up the variables needed for ROS workspace.